# WPF deserialize issue, communication exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

There is an asp.net based backend, where I use wcf services to communicate with client, which is a WPF application. When the data comes back from server, and during deserialization, it throws a communication exception. Here is the exception:

Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'AutoImportGetProtokolls'. The input source is not correctly formatted.

Source: http://pastebin.com/ZtUxYNUm

Here is a photo about the exception: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5araq9oajhrhrty/communicationexception.png?dl=0

I have another application based on silverlight, and when I call the same service, the exception does not come. After I start the WPF application the exception comes every time for first service call, after that it comes "randomly" (I could not find any logic when)

What I have tried so far but did not help:

-I used a DTO (data transfare object) class instead of generated one by entity framework. (sp_AutoImport_GetProtokolls_Result)

-Deleted the "out ErrorCustomModel res" parameter from service.

-Many source in google said that I should take a look for webconfing, and increase the property value of readerquotas. Here is the relevant part of webconfig: pastebin.com/e4ZpQsMK

Thank you guys, every hint are welcome.

Best Regards,
Norbert

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case because You don't say much about your service application, but in the past I had a similar problem on an http client server application due to the serialization formatting, in our case it was an object serialized in XML, the serialization process added the BOM at the beginning of the string that is used by file based data exchange to recognize the type of encoding (notepad for example uses BOM to recognize file contents) anyway, the .Net serializer has an option to serialize without BOM that we used to eliminate problem. You should give it a try